# socket.getaddrinfo fails on one machine; works on another apparently-identical one. Why?

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I've got a laptop and a desktop, both running Ubuntu 10.04, both running the stock Python 2.6.5 that comes with Ubuntu.

On the laptop, the following program

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import socket
print(socket.getaddrinfo("localhost", 8025, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM))
```

works -- i.e., it prints out some stuff without getting an error.

The stuff, in fact, is:

```
[(10, 1, 6, '', ('::1', 8025, 0, 0)), (2, 1, 6, '', ('127.0.0.1', 8025))]
```

(That's one bunch of IPv6 data, and one bunch of IPv4 data.)

However, on the other box, the same program does this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "socktest.py", line 5, in <module>
    print(socket.getaddrinfo("localhost", 8025, 0, socket.SOCK_STREAM))
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Why?

The laptop is x86 (i.e., 32-bit) whereas the desktop is x86_64, but I'd be surprised if that mattered.  The laptop also has two network interfaces (wireless and wired), whereas the desktop just has wired; again I doubt that's relevant.  All three interfaces were bound to IPv6 addresses, according to "ifconfig".  I diffed /etc/network on the two boxes, and saw no difference, except that the laptop has this clause

```
# The primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

... which, again, strikes me as irrelevant.

::

If you want some context: my Python program is trying to send email, and it's the email software that is ultimately calling getaddrinfo.

Comment: Does "ping localhost" work properly on both?

Comment: Other files to check: `/etc/services` and `/etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: I have the exact same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/q/32008965/936293. The problem machine's /etc/resolv.conf has 192.168.80.254 (home router) on the first line and the ISP's DNS server on the second. `dig` shows that requests to 192.168.80.254 runs fine, but `getaddrinfo` just won't. If I swop the two lines in /etc/resolv.conf it works, but on each DHCP refresh this gets reset. Frustrating. Any tips?

Answer (score 1):

Check `/etc/hosts` on the box where it does not work. Is there an entry for localhost?
Also compare `/etc/nsswitch.conf` and see if there is anything suspicious, like missing 'hosts' line

Comment: /etc/hosts is identical on both boxes, other than whitespace and the actual host names.  Each has two entries for "localhost": one for IPv4 and one for IPv6.

/etc/nsswitch.conf is identical on both boxes; each has a "hosts:" line.

Comment: Can you do telnet localhost 8025 on both?