# Where does getaddrinfo go for name resolution?

Tags: python, sockets, python-3.x

I have a Raspberry Pi.

`ping abc.azurewebsites.net` returns the IP address without issue.

However, `socket.getaddrinfo('abc.azurewebsites.net',80)` 
gives:

> socket.gaierror: [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname.

[image]

To make sure that the error is clear and isolated, I tried the above two commands on another Pi in another network and that one works fine.

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Weird issue, because normally it would look to DNS i guess...

Comment: Python just wraps the [C `getaddrinfo` function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html). I believe the `ping` command just uses `gethostbyname()`, see https://www.cs.utah.edu/~swalton/listings/sockets/programs/part4/chap18/ping.c

Comment: Take a lok at `/etc/resolv.conf` to see how DNS name resolution is configured on both systems - maybe that's the difference

Comment: Both systems have the gateway (a residential router) IP address in resolv.conf.  The question is still why `ping` and `getaddrinfo` have different outcomes.

Comment: I removed one of the duplicated lines in `resolv.conf` and the problem went away.